# Passive voice + ようにする

Tags: sentence, grammar

I came across with this problem:

```
彼女はその場を離れようとしなかった。
母親に手を引かれるようにしても、
何故かパイプ椅子から立ち上がろうとしなかった。?
```

what would be the meaning of "ようにする"? My dictionary says: "ようにする. try to, make sure to" so with that definition it would say that "Even though she was trying to be pulled by her mother, for some reason she didn't make an effort to get up from the chair." but she doesn't want to leave in the first place.

Or maybe she was trying or making an effort for 2 things at the same time? I mean, she knows that she has to leave that place, for that reason she extended her hand (trying to be pulled), but although that she doesn't want to leave, and tries to not get up from that chair? Or I'm just going crazy?
I don't understand why the second sentence is in passive voice and the other two are in active voice. Someone told me that the second one is speaking about the mother's attempt, but no why is that.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/49132/9831