# Two forms for trying to do

Tags: grammar

I m wondering what the difference is between verb dictionary form + you ni suru ( ryouri wo tsukuru you ni suru = to try cooking) vs volatioal + to suru ( ryouri wo tsukurou to suru ). Both apparently mean to tr something something
Are they equivalent ?
Also, is the volational you ending (for ru verbs) related to the you as above in the first example?

Comment: Or this: [Difference in meaning between ようとする and ようにする？Meaning of のか in this question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/49131/43676)

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. I dont know why you ni suru alyways gets translated as try to do in textbooks. I had the meaning right in the first place but was then cinfused by it