# "Try not to" in japanese

Tags: word-choice

食べないようとする

食べようとしない

Both the sentence above means "I will try not to eat". What's the difference

Comment: Just to confirm,  you definitely meant to type 食べないよう**に**する rather than 食べないよう**と**する, right?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with たべないようにする.

Comment: @Ben I didn't say there was anything wrong with たべないようにす. But it doesn't mean 'try', and it was different from his second example so I just wanted the OP to clarify/confirm his intention.

Comment: @user3856370, can you explain why 〜しないようにする doesn't mean 'try (not to 〜)'?

Comment: 「たべないよう**と**する」 is incorrect and makes no sense.

Comment: @Chocolate Clearly I'm confused. My understanding of ようにする is "will make sure to ...". To me this is a stronger statement than "will try to ...". The latter allows the possibility of failure. The former does not. Am I right about this? You say that ...ないようとする is incorrect, so how would you express "try not to ..." rather than "make sure not to ..."? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: ^ Try not to.. は 「まいとする」ですかね・・

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks. I thought that まいとする was rather formal sounding though, isn't it?

Comment: ^ そうですね。「しないよう**に**する」でもいいですね。

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33068/9831

Answer (score 7):

> 食べない**ように**する

The ように is the auxiliary (比況・例示・推定の助動詞)「[様]{よう}だ」.
It follows the attributive form (連体形) of a verb. It can conjugate to ように, ような, etc. but not to ようと.

> 食べ**よう**としない

The よう is the volitional auxiliary (意志の助動詞)「う・よう」.
It follows the imperfective form (未然形) of a verb, and is followed by ～と(する).

Compare:

The ように is the 比況・例示・推定 auxiliary [様]{よう}だ in:
「連体形+**ように**する」(make sure... / make an effort so that...)
「ない+**ように**する」(make sure... not / make an effort so that... won't)
vs
The よう is the volitional auxiliary う・よう in:
「未然形+**よう**とする」(try to do)
「未然形+**よう**としない」(don't try to do)

---

So...
食べないようにする means "make sure that I don't eat" "try not to eat".
(cf. 食べるようにする means "make sure that I eat" "try to eat")
食べようとしない means "don't try to eat" "won't eat".
(cf. 食べようとする means "try to eat")

Example:

> 「最近太ったので、脂っこいものは**食べないようにし**ています。」
>   (I've gained weight recently, so I'm trying not to eat / I've been avoiding fatty food.)
>   「好物のどらやきを出しても、**食べようとしない**んです。病気じゃないでしょうか。」
>   (I offered him his favorite Dorayaki, but he didn't try to eat it / he wouldn't eat it. I'm wondering if he's ill.)

---

For "try not to do", we also have ～**まい**とする, eg 食べまいとする.

「食べないよう**と**する」「～ないよう**と**する」 are grammatically incorrect.
 (「～ない+よう+と」「連体形+よう+と」「食べるようと」 are incorrect.)

Related:

- [Understand the difference between [dictionary/ない + ようとする] and [volitional + にする]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33068/9831)

Answer (score 3):

> 食べないようにする

This is OK for saying something like "I try not to eat (something)"

カロリーの高いものを食べないようにしている

"I try not to eat things which have a lot of calories"

> 食べようとしない
>
> Both the sentence above means "I will try not to eat". What's the difference

たべようとしない means more like "I will not (even) attempt to eat (something)". Like

納豆なんかは食べようとしない = I don't even bother trying to eat natto.

Comment: Can I take it that the proper way to say "I will try not to eat" is either 食べないようとする or 食べないようにする　?

Comment: I've done what I can to answer the first part of the question too.

Comment: 食べようとしない doesn't mean 'I'll try not to eat.' It means the way "it seems he/she doesn't try to eat." 私は食べようとしない is grammatically wrong.

Comment: ^ But 食べようとしない can mean "**I** try not to eat", no? 「私が食べようとしないので、お母さんが捨ててしまった。」とか。

Comment: その場合も、判断しているのは自分ではないのでは？ My mother thinks that I am not going to eat the dish and she put it into trash. ×私は〜しようとしない (するの重複)　○私は〜しないようにする　△(穴馬)　私は〜しようとする

Comment: 文学的に『私』を主人公に見立てている場合、あるいは過去の自分を振り返っては、成り立ちますね　それは仰る通りだ　しかし、日常会話ではちょっとヤバい感じがします